# Why does Windows 10 no longer load required DLLs from %PATH% and executable file’s directory’s?

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, path, dll

Just updated to Windows 10 1809 build 181305.1003 and it appears that if a DLL is required on start‑up (before the application starts) it doesn’t gets loaded leaving for example an error message stating `Qt5Gui.dll` couldn’t be found even if `Qt5Gui.dll` is in the same folder as the `.exe` file to be started.

Looks like ᴅʟʟ loading from directory from which the executable loaded is disabled while third party DLL loading from `%systemroot%\System32` still works. How to fix this since this prevent applications from using Qt5 ?

Comment: An other explaination is Microsoft changed the policy in Insider build about https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order so such directories are no longer included in search path.

Comment: Why the heck did you use this odd Latin small text: [`ᴅʟʟ`](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=ᴅʟʟ) instead of just typing DLL?

Comment: @Ramhound maybe there’s a post saying so ? I don’t have the problem if I use build before around october so it really behave like a policy change although I didn’t go as far as testing all of them. Maybe there’s a post about this because I wouldn’t had Googled correctly.

Comment: @Run5k yes, question edited.

Comment: @Ramhound yes that what’s I thought. They introduced a new setting which is enabled by Default. See `CWDIllegalInDllSearch`

Comment: @Ramhound Introduced in Vista only as something to be installed. Now enabled without add‑ons.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Many style guides (e.g. for The Economist) suggest setting initialisisms in small capitals so that they don't stand out to much in running text. Not really appropriate for a StackOverflow question, especially one full of numbers and monospaced filenames, but not entirely unheard of.

Comment: @ArthurTacca that s how I was taught to write manually.

Comment: @user2284570 Sorry, but small caps like that really are not commonly used for online purposes. The styles used in (predominantly) print publications like *The Economist* really don’t work well online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should disable `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\SafeDllSearchMode` on install! It may even fix other DLL problems that the user has!

And if that stops working we can always go back to installing all the DLLs directly into `%SystemRoot%\System32`, like in the good old days!